Retrieving Docker Image Labels from Google Artifact Registry
Is there any way to retrieve the labels of a docker image from Google artifact registry using their client library or their API?
I am trying to retrieve the labels of a docker image from Google artifact registry.
The client requests don't seem to return the labels of an image.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
